# How do I fix this while loop in C?

Tags: c, while-loop

I want to ask the user for a year, and if the user inputs a number bigger than 0, the program will run and when finished ask for a year again, and if the user inputs a 0, the program will end. Currently, the code works perfectly but only once. So the only thing I need fixing, is the while loop. When I start the code, it asks for a year, I give a year, and the answer is outputted, but then the program ends, whereas I want it to continuously ask for years, until I input '0' to end the program.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

/* 7.2 */
/* Julian Calendar */
int main()
{
    int year = 1;
    while (year > 0)
    {
        printf("Year: ");                /* Request year as input */
        scanf("%d", &year);              /* Accept/read year "year" */
        if (year <= 1582)
        {   
            if (year % 4 == 0)           /* If year is divisible by 4 */
            {
                if (year % 100 == 0)     /* If year is divisible by 100 */
                {
                    if (year % 400 == 0) /* If year is divisible by 400 */
                        printf("%4d is a leap year.\n", year);     /* Yes */
                    else
                        printf("%4d is not a leap year.\n", year); /* No */
                }
                else printf("%4d is a leap year.\n", year);        /* Yes */
            }
            else printf("%4d is not a leap year.\n", year);        /* No */
            return 0;
        }
        /* Gregorian Calendar */
        else if (year % 4 == 0)          /* If year is divisible by 4 */
            {
                if (year % 100 == 0)     /* If year is divisible by 100 */
                {
                    if (year % 400 != 0) /* If year is not divisible by 400 */
                        printf("%4d is not a leap year.\n", year); /* No */
                    else
                        printf("%4d is a leap year.\n", year);     /* Yes */
                }
                else printf("%4d is a leap year.\n", year);        /* Yes */
            }
            else printf("%4d is not a leap year.\n", year);        /* No */
     }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you. 
Sorry for my first iteration of the question not being clear.

Comment: And what is wrong with your program or your loop? Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also try to avoid `fflush(stdin)`. Passing an input-only stream to `fflush` is explicitly mentioned in the C specification as undefined behavior.

Comment: I would guess the "return 0" is somehow strange

Comment: Start by adopting a conventional and consistent coding style. I wouldn't recommend using Apple-goto-fail style.

Comment: Lundin, I wouldn't know what the conventional coding style is that you're referring too. I'm new to programming and this is the format I've been taught so far in my university course. Would you mind pointing me to some model examples or helpful tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only bug I think is in this code is :

```
return 0;
```

If you enter a value for `year` that is less than or equal to "1582", then it will result in the `return 0;` line of code being run, in effect, ending your while-loop and the `main()` function altogether.

You need to remove that line from inside the while-loop and instead put it just as the last line of `main()`:

```
int main()
{
    int year = 1;
    while (year > 0)
    {
        // Rest of code
    }

    return 0;        // Put return statement here instead if inside the while() loop

}
```

**As an aside**, just as @SomeProgrammerDude mentioned in his comment, you do not need to use `fflush(stdin)` as in your case, it will lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: I'm new to this website, so I'll ask, am I really meant to avoid saying thanks? Anyway, thank you very much. I moved the _return 0_  to the last line of _main_ and my code is now looping perfectly.

Comment: @RichardRobertson No harm in a "thanks" message. Good to hear that your program works now :-)

Answer (score 2):

The only thing i can suggest you with this details is something like this :

```
  do {
       //ask for year input...
       ....
       ....
      if (year==0) {
        flag++;
      }
    while(flag==0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for( ; ; ) {
  //ask for year
  //
  if(year<1) break;
  // do the work
}
```